# Setting up Linode (Ubuntu 10.04 32bit) nginx not starting. 98: address already in use

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04, railscasts, linode

Hello having a little issue with setting up linode via Railscast instructions of Ep. #335

My Configuration for this server is: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Disk Image 32bit

I can get this far:

Running both of these work as expected.

`apt-get -y update`

`apt-get -y install curl git-core python-software-properties`

When I get to the nginx steps:

`add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable`

`apt-get -y update`

`apt-get -y install nginx`

Up to this point all seems to be working properly.

It is here:`service nginx start`

that I get the following in response:

```
 * Starting nginx nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

I have tried stopping, restarting and reloading nginx but I cannot get anything to change.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have something else running or blocking that port.
try running: sudo netstat -pan | grep ":80"

which should give you a hint on what is running on there. Maybe its a uwsgi/apache2/tomcat etc. Could be a lot running there.

EDIT:

i now know whats the problem as i had it myself now on a debian server.

```
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
```

You should comment the first or the second line (depends on if you want to listen of ipv6 or ipv4.
That was the problem i had.

Comment: Things i'd try:
1. sudo service nginx restart
2. Then try to reconfigure the nginx to use some other port if that works perfectly you should digg more into it.
3. post output of 
    sudo netstat -tulpean

Comment: sorry Stack Over Flow cut me off.

It returned: 

`udp        0      0 66.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx   80.xxx.xxx.xx:xxx       ESTABLISHED xxxx/ntpd`

Comment: did you really used: ":80" ??
```sudo netstat -pan | grep ":80"``` use everything in between the ```

Comment: when I use ":80" nothing when I use "80" I get the above results

Comment: just to be curious please do a ```ps aux | grep nginx```

Comment: root      3472  0.0  0.1   3376   748 pts/0    S+   18:32   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx

Comment: I changed the port to 81 to test and it still says the address is already in use

Comment: That was it. Much appreciated. I know this TY is long over due.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the proper solution, but it worked for me after I commented the line:

```
listen 80;
```

in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default